# How to make the compiler check an array length?

Tags: c, arrays, string, definition

I defined a function:

```
void myFunction(char string[20])
{
    // update my string here, maximal size is 20.
}
```

Calling the function with

```
char st[5];
myFunction(st);
```

is an error, because `myFunction` smashes the stack which leads to undefined behavior. Of course `st` should be of size 20 (or greater).

Is there a way to make the c compiler complain when such errors occur, and what is the recommended way to code such calls?

Comment: The only way you can know the length of the array (which as a function argument is actually a pointer) is to pass the length as another argument. The compiler will ignore the `20` in the definition: it is only used for a multi-dimensional array so that the compiler knows how to index it, for example `char string[][20]`. It is the entire responsibilty of the programmer in C not to break array bounds (except for initialising data, as part of the array definition).

Comment: The usual method that helps is to define the count/length and use that everywhere (e.g.): `#define COUNT 20` and do: `char st[COUNT];` and `void myFunction(char string[COUNT]) { for (int i = 0;  i < COUNT; ++i) string[i] = ...; }`. This is not exactly what you're asking for, but it's better than hardwiring the counts in all places. It also allows the count to be changed easily (e.g. `#define COUNT 37`) and all places are adjusted automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Of course st should be of size 20 (or greater).

You can make use of the static array indices feature of C99, available for use in [function declarators](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.7.5.3p7).

> If the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

So, you can declare the function as

```c
void myFunction(char string[static 20])
{
    /* ... */
}
```

instead. This will trigger a warning from the compiler if the array argument being passed contains anything less than 20 elements.

For example, when calling `myFunction` with `st` of type `char [5]`, clang 10 gives me `warning: array argument is too small; contains 5 elements, callee requires at least 20 [-Warray-bounds]`

However, for now only clang seems to have the support with `-Warray-bounds`, and GCC is planning to add support in the [future](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50584).

Note that this only works at compile time for arrays, but it also warns one when passing in NULL pointers (if that can be determined at compile time). However, someone may pass a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of elements less than 20, and the compiler cannot statically check that at compile time.

So for this case, it only works well when the declared type of the argument is `char [N]` where N is its size, and N is atleast 20. If you wish to handle both cases, an explicit size parameter will be needed, and a check inside the function to return an error in case the passed in size is smaller than 20.

Comment: This **may** trigger a warning from the compiler. The C standard does not require an implementation to diagnose this, and a compiler might or might not even if it can see the dimension of the array being used as an argument. And, of course, depending on circumstances, as you mention, the compiler might not be able to see that, as when it is passing a pointer received from elsewhere or calculated in a complicated way. For example, Apple Clang 11.0 diagnosis this when `myFunction(st)` is used but not when `myFunction(st+1)` is used.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Correct. All that defining a parameter as `char string[static 20]` rather than `char string[20]` does is cause any call that *doesn't* pass a pointer to the initial element of an array of at least 20 elements to have undefined behavior. It allows for warnings, but a conforming compiler could silently ignore the `static` (and the `20`).

Comment: Right, but note that the original question poses two requirements, that the compiler check for the size of the array being passed in at compile time, and that it be *atleast* 20 (the first quote), both of which are only possible with the use of static and a compiler implementing warnings. So while its true the standard doesn't require a conforming compiler to implement warnings, it's useful to make use of it for ones that do.

Answer (score 2):

You could encapsulate the array:

```
struct string20 { char string[20]; };
void myFunction(struct string20 *string)
{
}
```

or pass around pointers to the array (!= pointers to the first item):

```
void myFunction( char (*string)[20] )
{
}
//....
char st[5];
char st20[20];
myFunction(&st); //WRONG; diagnosed error
myFunction(&st20); //OK
```

Using either of these approaches you will get compiler diagnostics regardless of your platform
(as long as it's a standard conforming platform).

Answer (score 1):

Your function looks like this:

```c
void myFunction(char string[20])
{
    // update my string here, maximal size is 20.
}
```

But, the compiler sees it like this:

```c
void myFunction(char *string)
{
    // update my string here, maximal size is 20.
}
```

The size "20" means literally nothing to the compiler. You can call the function with array of any length.

Regarding the call with:

```c
char st[5];
myFunction(st);
```

It's totally okay.

If you want to enforce a specific array size, you could wrap the array in a struct.

Comment: The size “20” does not literally mean nothing to the compiler, nor does the compiler see an array parameter declaration solely as a pointer parameter declaration. Although the C standard specifies that array parameter declarations are adjusted to pointer declarations, the declaration is subject to constraints and processing prior to that adjustment. For example, `void MyFunction(char string[20][])` will produce an error because the array element type is incomplete, but `void MyFunction(char (*string)[])` will not.

Comment: And a call to `void MyFunction(char string[puts("foo")])` may print “foo” (does in GCC and Clang, if I recall correctly, but the C standard is unclear on the required behavior), showing the array declaration has effects besides just being a pointer declaration.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, the C standard says "If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression: if it occurs in a declaration at function prototype scope, it is treated as if it were replaced by *".  I take that to mean that a conforming implementation will not evaluate the `puts` call in your example.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: *Function prototype scope* is for non-definition declarations only, per C 2018 6.2.1 4. In a function definition, the parameter declaration has block scope.